# how can I link commvalt to lacal database

Tags: database, cloud

how many possible ways that I can automate the process of commvault linking to my local data base
so that entire process happens dynamically from next time, when ever I work on it instead of commanding manually everytime.
answer with explanation and few steps involved in process if possible.